Installing pgvector in Bitnami Postgres Helm Chart
I need to use "pgvector" extension and I would like to use the bitnami's postgres helm chart in order to have the advantages of the helm chart confgurations.
https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector
https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/postgresql/15.5.16

This answer is based on a proposal on github by user "coronabytes":
https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues/32677

Create a multistage dockerfile let's call it Dockerfile_pgvector

FROM pgvector/pgvector:pg16 AS builder

FROM bitnami/postgresql:16.3.0-debian-12-r19

COPY --from=builder /usr/lib/postgresql/16/lib/vector.so /opt/bitnami/postgresql/lib/
COPY --from=builder /usr/share/postgresql/16/extension/vector* /opt/bitnami/postgresql/share/extension/


Build, tag and push your image to your registry

docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/my-company/project/bitnami/postgresql -f Dockerfile_pgvector .

docker push registry.gitlab.com/my-company/project/bitnami/postgresql


Note that it is important that the image is called bitnami/postgresql
Edit your bitnami helm chart's values

postgresql:
  architecture: standalone
  image:
    tag: latest
    pullPolicy: Always
    registry: registry.gitlab.com/my-company/project
    pullSecrets:
      - gitlab-registry-secret


Note the registry stops at the project, the chart is configured to always search "bitnami/postgres" as image.

